# Reverse negatives for numeric values according to category in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a data frame that looks like so:

| colour | evaluation |
| --- | --- |
| white | 1.00 |
| black | - 0.50 |
| white | - 0.60 |
| black | 1.50 |

Evaluations is a numeric data type.

I want to create code that flips all the symbols of all evaluations with the colour black, so + becomes - and - becomes +, to create a table like so:

| colour | evaluation |
| --- | --- |
| white | 1.00 |
| black | 0.50 |
| white | - 0.60 |
| black | - 1.50 |

This is the dput() output of the first 20 rows of my data frame:

```
structure(list(nnue_diff = c(NA, 0.12, -0.05, 0.06, -0.03, 0.13, 
-0.05, 0.02, 0.13, -0.22, -0.08, 0.07, -0.2, 0.24, -0.16, 0.32, 
1.18, -1.23, -0.06, 0), colour = c("white", "black", "white", 
"black", "white", "black", "white", "black", "white", "black", 
"white", "black", "white", "black", "white", "black", "white", 
"black", "white", "black")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Does anyone know a method for doing so?

Comment: Try `myData[ myData$colour == "black", "evaluation"] <- myData[ myData$colour == "black", "evaluation"] * -1`

Comment: Would you `dput(your_data)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on updated data

```
library(dplyr)

df |> mutate(nnue_diff = case_when(colour == "black" ~ nnue_diff * -1 , TRUE ~ nnue_diff))
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 20 × 2
   nnue_diff colour
       <dbl> <chr> 
 1     NA    white 
 2     -0.12 black 
 3     -0.05 white 
 4     -0.06 black 
 5     -0.03 white 
 6     -0.13 black 
 7     -0.05 white 
 8     -0.02 black 
 9      0.13 white 
10      0.22 black 
11     -0.08 white 
12     -0.07 black 
13     -0.2  white 
14     -0.24 black 
15     -0.16 white 
16     -0.32 black 
17      1.18 white 
18      1.23 black 
19     -0.06 white 
20      0    black
```

Comment: It would be worth mentioning what to do if those are numeric values, not strings.  This is why `dput()` of the data is important, as you requested.

Comment: Thanks for the help, would you be able to specify what to do if evaluations is a numeric data type?

Comment: Then you have to edit your post and paste the result of  ‘dput(your_data)’ to let us help .

Answer (score -1):

Use the `swap` function from the `textclean` package

```r
df <- data.frame(colour = c("white", "black", "white", "black"), evaluation = c("+ 1.00", "- 0.50", "- 0.60", "+ 1.50"))

library(dplyr); library(textclean)
df %>% 
  mutate(evaluation = ifelse(colour == 'black', swap(evaluation,'+', '-'), evaluation))

  colour evaluation
1  white     + 1.00
2  black     + 0.50
3  white     - 0.60
4  black     - 1.50
```